# Django model form not producing expected HTML

Tags: python, django, file, forms, upload

I have a modelform that doesn't produce (some of) the HTML that (should) represent the model fields.  As you can see from the output at the bottom, it's just outputting a blank line where it should be outputting the title and presumably a browse button (or something--right?) for the filefield.

```
#views.py
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('files/upload_file.html', { 'form': form })

#models.py
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UploadFile(models.Model):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    theFile = forms.FileField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(title)

class UploadFileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadFile

#upload_file.html
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>

#The HTML output
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually on second thought your mistake is in declaring your model UploadFile (after doublechecking due to lack of a response).  You are supposed to use models.CharField not forms.CharField.  Thus your model doesn't have any content; hence the ModelForm doesn't have any fields (it didn't arise as an error just in case some advanced user wanted to attach the form fields you eventually wanted to use to a model).  You also will need to give the FileField an upload_to location, principally your media directory.

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    theFile = models.FileField(upload_to="files/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(title)
```

Comment: Hmmm I see.  That (sort of) occured to me since I did write something similar using models.foo rather than forms.foo with no problems.  However the Django documentation specifically uses forms.foo when dealing with file uploads in particular, so that's what I used.  Interesting.  Thank you!

Comment: @Harv: Where in the docs, I can't find good example of FileUpload in a model.  Say at  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/ they only give an example with a form (ie, a class that generates html forms) correctly defining the fields in the form using forms.Char/FileField with no model.   You create a Model (a class of info to store in the db) and then make a form with ModelForm (that generates the form with forms.*Field out of the model).  The model should never have forms.*Field in it as that has to do with making an HTML form rather than saving info in a db.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the doc I was referring to.  I suppose I just assumed you would build a form with the intention of storing the data somewhere, and the docs don't seem to indicate otherwise.  I understand what you're saying about models never having forms.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I should have been reading http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/ instead.